# Find a specific filename in a specific subdirectory with gsutil ls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a Google Cloud Platform Storage bucket `bucket` with a `top-level-folder`. I want to list a file with specific `extension` that could be located in any `sub-directory` withing the top the level folder. How can I do that?

Basically I am having trouble using the glob pattern twice.

`gsutil ls gs://bucket/top-level-folder/*/**<sub-directory>/**/*.<extension>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is:

`gsutil ls gs://bucket/top-level-folder/**<sub-directory>**.<extension>`

This will list all the files under top-level-directory which end in the desired extension

**EDIT:**
I changed the code to include the subdirectory on the gsutil command.

Comment: But the file also has to be within the `<sub-directory>` so the search space can be reduced as well.